# Can mockito-inline mock private methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, mockito-inline

I know that Mockito (mockito-core) does not mock private, static, and final methods, but I found that mockito-inline can mock static and final methods. But I could not find whether it can or cannot mock private methods. If it is possible, can someone provide an example.

P.S. I know mocking private methods is not a good practice. I also know that PowerMock can be used for mocking private methods.